# Duplicated elements in Generic Lists

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, generics

I am trying to find out, why in the following example does not the generic list add duplicated elements?. If my collection "Categories" associated to my class articles already has a category ex. (Category {id =1, name ="example1"}) and I want to add the same category (Category {id =1, name ="example1"})". It does not add this element to the collection because it is already there.

```
var articleToUpdate = _ctx.Articles.Include("Categories").Where(r => r.Id == id).SingleOrDefault(); 
var categories = _ctx.Categories;


foreach (var item in categories)
            {
              articleToUpdate.Categories.Add(item);
            }
```

This is the class definition:

```
 public class Article
{

    public int Id { get; set; }


    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Body { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Author { get; set; }


    public ICollection<ArticleComment> Comments { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean _"add duplicated elements"_? What is the output you are expecting and what is the actual result?

Comment: I mean if my collection "Categories" associated to my class articles already has a category ex. (Category {id =1, name ="example1"}) and I want to add the same category (Category {id =1, name ="example1"})". it does not add this element to the collection because it is already there.

Comment: Sorry Stephen but Johnny could understood my question and i have got a really interesting answer. so I do not understand why it has been put as unclear?

Comment: Read the first 2 words of Johnny's answer and it should be clear why your question is unclear.

Comment: ok. I will keep it on mind for next questions. appreciate it.

Comment: You have now edited your question to make it clearer (what your expect the result to be and what the actual result is) so I'll nominate to reopen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that your `ICollection<Category>` is actually instantiated as a `HashSet`. Try an `IList<Category>` instead, or see if you can define that attribute as a bag.

Comment: but why is ICollection<Category> going to be instantiated as a HashSet? I have not done it explicitly. Can it happens by default?

Comment: Well you can debug your code and see it. Put a breakpoint over the line where you add the categories, hover over the variable, you'll see what the real type is. It could happen by default, yes.

Comment: Yes. you are right, In the raw view i have got: ((System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<DBayonaCode.Domain.Entities.Category>)(articleToUpdate.Categories)). but why does it happen by default? How can i change this behavior?.

Comment: Glad you found it. Try writing IList<Category> instead of ICollection<Category>. The reason for having a set is as default is performance: When you remove one of the elements in categories, with a list implementation the EF would actually delete all and reinsert all except the removed category. With a set implementation it only deletes the removed category.

Comment: Ok. I change to IList and it added the duplicated object. wow. I really appreciate your help. It would have taken ages to be aware of it.